# How to connect to existing sqlite database in phonegap

Tags: phonegap-build

I use phonegap for create an android application. 
I did these steps :
1. Wrote html, css and jquery mobile codes.
2. Include phonegap.js into  .
3. Create the database via sqlite manager firefox extension and copy to root the project directory (beside index.html).
4. use this code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        onDeviceReady();
        queryDB();
        $("#links").niceScroll();
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady()
    {
        var db = window.openDatabase("shia.sqlite", "1.0", "shia", 100000);
    }

    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM posts', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }

    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        console.log("Returned rows = " + results.rows.length);
        // this will be true since it was a select statement and so rowsAffected was 0
        if (!results.rowsAffected) {
            console.log('No rows affected!');
            return false;
        }
        // for an insert statement, this property will return the ID of the last inserted row
        console.log("Last inserted row ID = " + results.insertId);
    }

    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }
</script>
```

This error displayed into console :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'executeSql' of undefined

Please help me .

Answer (score 1):

@Behzad,
your code has the function

```
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM posts', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}
```

However, when you call `queryDB`, you did not pass the handle. So in this function the parameter `tx` is null because you did not pass the handle.